# R Studio Github md file no pictures

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown

I am not sure if its supposed to be this way, but after I converted my R markdown to .md file for github, the pictures are not displayed? They are displayed in R-studio but not github? am i missing something

i am using the following

```
output:
  github_document: default
```